# What is the proper way to request insightTrafficSourceDetail in youtube's analytics API?

Tags: youtube-api, analytics

I can see from the docs that insightTrafficSourceDetail is only available for certain combinations of dimensions/filters/number of results, however I can't seem to get a legit query going.

For example:

> metrics=views&dimensions=insightTrafficSourceDetail&filter=insightTrafficSourceType==GOOGLE_SEARCH&max-results=1

That seems like it should work to me based on the docs, but I get this:

> {"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"badRequest","message":"The
>   query is not supported. Check the documentation for supported
>   queries."}],"code":400,"message":"The query is not supported. Check
>   the documentation for supported queries."}

Tried many other combinations to no avail.

I noticed a couple of bug reports around this, so maybe it's broken?

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3995

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3963

Answer (score 3):

This query is only available on video level. This means you have to add to filters "video==%some-video-id%"

See
http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtubeAnalytics/v1/youtubeAnalytics.reports.query?ids=channel%253D%253DYOUR_CHANNEL_ID_HERE&start-date=2010-01-01&end-date=2013-02-12&metrics=views&dimensions=insightTrafficSourceDetail&filters=insightTrafficSourceType%253D%253DYT_SEARCH%253Bvideo%253D%253DYOUR_VIDEO_ID_HERE&max-results=25&sort=-views&_h=8&

And:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/available_reports
Section about channel reports (insightTrafficSourceDetail)

Cheers

Comment: That works, thanks!  The the mentioned docs page is not at all clear about that - "In addition, the following channel reports are supported as long as the requested result set is limited." - I expect that I can limit the result set with max-results, but it fails unless a video filter is in place.